# how to call the parent method of another method in dojo

Tags: javascript, dojo

how could i call the parent method of another method in dojo.
consider the following example:

```
var parent = declare(null,{

m1: function(arg){
console.log("parent.m1");
},
m2: function(arg){
console.log("parent.m2");
}

});`enter code here`

var child = declare(parent,{

m1: function(arg){
console.log("child.m1");
// how can i call parent.**m2** here directly without calling child.m2
},
m2: function(arg){
console.log("child.m2");
}

});
```

how can i call parent.m2 directly from child.m1 without invoking child.m2 at all

now suppose i define two modules as the following:

```
parentModule.js

    var parent = declare(null,{

    m1: function(arg){
    console.log("parent.m1");
    },
    m2: function(arg){
    console.log("parent.m2");
    }

    });
    return declare("ParentModule",[parent,child]);
//******************************************//
childModule.js

    return declare("child",null,{

    m1: function(arg){
    console.log("child.m1");
    // how can i call parent.**m2** here directly without calling child.m2
    //if we call ParentModule.prototype.m2.call(this,arguments); this will call child.m2
    //as child module override the parent now
    //also calling this.getInherited("m2",arguments); will call child.m2 !!!
    //how to fix that?
    },
    m2: function(arg){
    console.log("child.m2");
    }

    });
```

Comment: I am confused by your hierarchy.  Why is Parent extending the Child?  Shouldn't it be the other way around?  I posted a jsfiddle that shows how I think you should define your modules.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When using dojo's declare you can use `this.inherited(arguments)` in the child function to call the parent function, see:

http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dojo/_base/declare.html#dojo-base-declare-safemixin

```
m1: function (arg) {
    console.log("child.m1");
    this.inherited(arguments);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the javascript's prototype functionality to accomplish what you are asking.

```
m1: function(arg){
    console.log("child.m1");
    parent.prototype.m2.apply(this, arguments);
},
```

More about prototype can be found here [How does JavaScript .prototype work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/572897/how-does-javascript-prototype-work)

Here is an example of this working
http://jsfiddle.net/cswing/f9xLf/